# Form not Displaying in Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, forms

I am making a form using Django 1.8 and Python 3.5 
But the form is not showing up,IDK why ?

This are my files respectivel

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login', 'login.views.login', name='login'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL , document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**login/view.py==**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import allusers1
# Create your views here.
def login(request):
    form1=allusers1()
    context = {
         "form1": form1

     }
    return render(request, "login.html",context)
```

**login/forms.py==**

```
from django import forms

from .models import allusers1

class signupform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = allusers1
        fields = ['name','phoneno']
```

**login/models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class allusers1(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=400)
    phoneno=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    otp=models.IntegerField()

    # def __str__(self):
    #     return self.name
```

**login.html**

```
{{form1}}
```

**output**

```
allusers1 object
```

But output should have been Name and ,Email fields for input

**WHAT IS THE ERROR ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is actually named `signupform`, and not `allusers1`.

In your **views.py**, you should import your form like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import signupform  # <= here
# Create your views here.
def login(request):
    form1=signupform()  # <= and here
    context = {
         "form1": form1

     }
    return render(request, "login.html",context)
```

Comment: U saved My life man ,If I had enough opoints I would have triple upvoted you up